# Grabbing the Data from an Axios API call error

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios

I am working on an app that on occasion deals with bad data (the data architect is aware, but won't be fixing it any time soon).  The resulting bad data is causing a 404 errors when I call to the record. When I run the API call in postman, it still returns a 404 error, but passes the status and message as a data payload.
I am looking for a way to grab the status and message from the data element so I can display the message in the client.  I would rather just do the error handling on the front-end and populate a message if no data is returned, but my project lead insists on doing it server side.

this is the type of response I am getting from axios.  when I check in the console.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Request failed with status code 404 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}message: "Request failed with status code 404"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: '(redacted from privacy)', __zone_symbol__loadendfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYloadend: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYabort: ƒ, …}response: 
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data: {status: 0, message: 'Data is not found'}
headers: {cache-control: 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', connection: 'keep-alive', content-type: 'application/json', date: 'Thu, 03 Aug 2023 21:06:06 GMT', expires: '0', …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: 'http://localhost:8080/labtrax/api/maintain/equipment/getById/?id=6', __zone_symbol__loadendfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYloadend: ƒ, __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYabort: ƒ, …}
status: 404
statusText: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Error
constructor: ƒ AxiosError(message, code, config, request, response)
toJSON: ƒ toJSON()
isAxiosError: true
[[Prototype]]: Object 
undefined
```

Here is my API call:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
         const res = await axios.get(`${detailsUrl + selectedRecord.id}`);
         setValues( res.data );
      } catch (error) {
         setValues( error.response.data ); // Added this line
         console.error(error.message);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I have tried calling to values.message as well as values.data.message, but nothing seems to populate.  How can I grab the message so I can display it in the client?  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just curious, have you ever logged `values`?

Comment: yes, as it currently is, if I log values, I get nothing but "[[Prototype]] Object"

Comment: This is exactly what it displays from my console log:    Values: {} [[Prototype]] Object

Comment: umm, you can use console.log(JSON.stringify(values))

Comment: when I console.log(JSON.stringify(values)) it just returns empty '{}'

Answer (score 0):

add `console.log(res)` in your try block and `console.log(error)` in catch block.

after that as per the log extract the desired value you want.

example message = res.data or anything else

Comment: wouldn't this just console log the response and the errors?  I need to set the data from the response to the values, so can call it inside of the component and display the message in the browser window.

Comment: yes once you log those you will get the returning object then extract it and set the desired value using setValues

Comment: Something like this?

React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(`${detailsUrl + selectedRecord.id}`);
      try {
        console.log(res)
        setValues( res.data );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        console.log(error)
        setValues( error );
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

Comment: yes and check in browser console. or just do console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) if unable to read whole values

Answer (score 0):

Simply add *setValues(error.response.data)* inside the catch to access the data from the error response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).